# Symfony2 Ajax changes to the full div after success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

SO I have a div which displays information from arrays. With my ajax script I am increasing a value in an array and I want the whole div to change accordingly... I have already made these changes, but I dont know how to change the whole div? DO I use .attr or something else?

This is the twig:

```
{% for key, item in cart %}
                {% if key == info.id %}

                    <div class="input-append">

                    <input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="{{ key }}" value="{{ item }}" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text" data-id="{{ key }}"/>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove btn"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add btn"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>

                    </div>

                  </td>

                  <td>{{ info.getQtyPrice(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.getQtyDiscount(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.getQtyTax(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>


                  <td>{{ info.getQtyFinal(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>


                </tr>
         {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
```

With Ajax I am increasing or decreasing the quantity(quantity is the variable item). When I increase or decrease the quantity I want the whole div to change accordingly. For example if the products quantity is 1 the price is 50, when I increase the quantity I want the price to change to 100. This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add/quantity',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {      
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }else{
            $this.parent('.input-append').val(data.amount)  
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Right now the line: `$this.parent('.input-append').val(data.amount)` only changes the quantity in the input field.

How can I change the whole div with the prices?

**Answer**

Thank you for your help. this code did the trick: `$('.table').load(" .table");`

Comment: Do you want to get only `<div class="input-append">` up-to-date? what about `<td>{{ info.getQtyPrice(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>` which is not inside your `div`?

Comment: Yes I want to update the whole table, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

add a class to each td you want to update like this :

```
                  <td class="qtyprice">{{ info.getQtyPrice(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
                  <td class="qtytax">{{ info.getQtyDiscount(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.getQtyTax(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
                  <td class="qtyfinal">{{ info.getQtyFinal(item)|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
```

and your Ajax you update those fields accordingly by selecting them by class :

```
success: function (data) {      
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }else{
            $this.closest('tr').find('.input-append').val(data.amount) ;
            $this.closest('tr').find('.qtyprice').val(data.qtyprice) ;
            $this.closest('tr').find('.qtytax').val(data.qtytax) ;
            $this.closest('tr').find('.qtyfinal').val(data.qtyfinal) ; 
           }
        }
```

your ajax response data needs to have all the prices on success.

Comment: Hey, I didnt check all of the prices but the line $this.parent('tr').find('.input-append').val(data.amount) ; didnt change anything

Comment: sorry its i update my code made a mistake its closest not parent, you understand what it is doing right ? i am not sure if you have a 'tr' around it but this select your closest tr and find your inputs inside it and update everything, there is no way around it you have to select all field you want to update then update them with the value you need